# Start symfony2 without server:run from command line

Tags: symfony

How can I browse a symfony2 website without starting the server from command line?

I cannot start the server from command because of some errors. Is there a way to visit the symfony2 app through url?

Comment: Have you tried sorting the errors?

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can, if you visit the site through localhost. But in this case as well you must use a webserver, such as the PHP build-in webserver (server:run), XAMPP, WAMP or something.

What type of error message you get?